# Can "lick up" be used instead of "lap up"?

Tags: word-usage

A cat "laps up" milk from a saucer. But can "lick up" be used instead?

> The cat's licking up milk from the saucer.

Can they be used interchangeably in this context? And are they equally likely to be used?

Answer (score 3):

No, licking is not about drinking, although a cat uses its tongue for both. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lap) has

> **lap** verb (2)
>   **1a**: to take in (food or drink) with the tongue
>   *a cat lapping milk from a dish*

However the cat might "lick the dish clean" to finish, but that is different from drinking. When drinking, a cat forms its tongue into a kind of spoon shape to scoop up the liquid, which is much more efficient than licking. So it's not just a different word, but a different action too.

---

There is also the associated phrase **lap up** about which [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lapped%20up) has

> **lap up** transitive verb
>   **1** to respond to enthusiastically or accept eagerly
>   *she simply lapped up admiration*

Associated with **lick** is **lick up** which is a slang phrase. [A dictionary of Slang](http://www.peevish.co.uk/slang/l.htm) has

> **lick up** Verb.
>   To fawn, to be obsequious.
>   *She licked up to the teacher and got a grade A in her English language test.*

Comment: However, if you spilled milk on the floor, you might well say that the cat was **licking up** the milk that you spilled. That's to say that it was licking the milk from the floor.

Comment: @RonaldSole yes, I guess that would be similar to the cat **licking** the last of the milk from a dish, becuase it isn't deep enough to **lap**.